# OS X modal application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6

Trying to figure out how to write an application that prevents a user from using any other application during a (user set) time period. Sort of like a "modal" application.

Have given up trying to disable the internet connection, so the next best thing would be to make the application itself modal, i.e. only the application has focus (in full screen mode) for a set period of time, with the user unable to switch applications or exit full screen.

Is this possible using Xcode and Cocoa?

Any hints appreciated!

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called [kiosk mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: THANK YOU!! You've just made my weekend. ;-)